# Windows 10: System Proxy Settings - How to force internet requests through a proxy for certain adresses?

Tags: windows, windows-10, proxy

Facts:

1. Windows has a configuration panel for proxy settings
2. This configuration is the default for all applications that use system internet connection settings
3. There are some applications that provides their own configuration for internet connections (overriding system internet configurations)
4. The Window Internet Setings pane provides a field to declare a list of address (semicolon separated; * wildcard allowed) to be excluded from proxy navigation

Setting up:

- A Proxy configurated on systems proxy settings
- An entry on the exclusion list for requests to a full domain addresses e.g. `*.adomain.com`

Is there a way to configure (or extend) the system proxy configuration to define a rule to force through proxy request to a specific address into the full domain exluded? e.g for the setting up above Is there a way to force proxy for `*.subdomain1.adomain.com` requests preserving the exclusion rule `*.adomain` for all other request ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with the built-in Windows proxy settings,
which are rather simple and primitive.

You will need to install a third-party proxy server on your computer,
then define it to Windows as your proxy. Such a proxy server can be
much more sophisticated.

A well-know such product is [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/),
which unfortunately is paid software.
It can use sophisticated
[Proxification Rules](https://www.proxifier.com/docs/win-v3/rules.htm).
Studying its documentation can help to understand the concept,
even if you do not intend to pay for it.

You could also have a look at the list of
[Proxifier alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/proxifier/)
(but I can make no recommendation).

Comment: +1 whenever deserved